# Генератор Python

Tags: python, генераторы

Есть список, необходимо вывести этот список по очереди через генератор, еще и с подписями

```
my_list = (Хлеб, 2, 35, Молоко, 1, 53, Яйцо, 30, 300)
x = (i for i in my_list)
next(x)

Пример
next(x)
output: Название: Хлеб
next(x)
output: Кол-во: 2
next(x)
output: Цена: 35
и т.д.
```

Comment: так и что не получилось?

Comment: Прикольная задача, но решается очень легко, в одну строчку. Попробуйте что-то сделать сами сначала.

Comment: @CrazyElf, zip/cycle ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да нет, в основном там `f`-строку вписать в заготовку генератора, она, правда, развесистая выходит, но это и почти всё. Хм, а про `zip` с самим собой списка мысль правильная, я ж так на днях и сам делал же, не подумал ))  А, нет, тут не поможет, кажется, нужно чтоб `next` же работал по очереди...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Генератор можно организовать как-то так. Нумеруем список и через остаток вычленяем из списка с подписями подпись к элементу списка.

```
my_list = ['Хлеб', 2, 35, 'Молоко', 1, 53, 'Яйцо', 30, 300, ]
fields = ['Название', 'Количество', 'Цена', ]

x = (print('{}: {}'.format(fields[ir % len(fields)], item)) for ir, item in enumerate(my_list))

for _ in my_list:  # Выводим в консоль
    next(x)
```

Или через `map` и `lambda`:

```
x = map(lambda f, m: print(f'{f}: {m}'), fields * (len(my_list) // len(fields)), my_list)
```

В итоге имеем что-то подобное:

```
Название: Хлеб
Количество: 2
Цена: 35
Название: Молоко
Количество: 1
Цена: 53
Название: Яйцо
Количество: 30
Цена: 300
```

Comment: Вот так и не дали человеку самому задание сделать )  По сути у меня было такое же решение, только можно короче сделать если через `f`-строку, а не через `format` написать

Comment: Я думаю, что человек справится сам)

Answer (score 4):

А если так?

```py
from itertools import cycle

my_list = ['Хлеб', 2, 35, 'Молоко', 1, 53, 'Яйцо', 30, 300, ]
fields = ['Название', 'Количество', 'Цена', ]

def gen(titles, data):
    for i, j in zip(cycle(titles), data):
        yield i + ": " + str(j)

a = gen(fields, my_list)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(a))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Можно в одну строку

```py
print(*(i + ": " + str(j) for i, j in zip(cycle(fields), my_list)), sep="\n")
```

Comment: По заданию требуется, чтобы `next(x)` без дополнительных телодвижений сам печатал уже готовую строку. Но так то через `cycle` красиво, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, можно и через next.